# Query delay using JPA and pg_sleep in native query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

trying to implement delay using `pg_sleep()` on PSQL side

```java
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT *, pg_sleep(:delay) FROM repayment_applications " +
            "WHERE repayment_applications.correlation_id = :correlationId " +
            "AND repayment_applications.status <> :status")
Optional<RepaymentApplication> findRepaymentApplicationCorrelationIdAndNotStatusWithDelay(
    @Param("delay") Long delay,
    @Param("correlationId") String correlationId,
    @Param("status") String status);
```

This query perfectly works in case of querying directly to DB with specified delay.
But when using JPA native query it occurs instantly without any delay.

The main task is to have a delay between queries to let other app update DB record.

Stack:

- spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.12
- postgresql:42.5.1.

There is also an idea to make a thread sleep like `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);`, but not sure it is a right decsision.

If there are any ideas how to make it work using current idea or using another approach to complete the task, please comment below. Thanks in advance

Comment: there seems to be a typo in your query - after `SELECT *` you have a comma, please remove it try again

Comment: @GoranLegenda without a comma the query has an invalid structure

Comment: The result of `pg_sleep(N)` for a given N is typically cached, and the function is not called every time. Try on the command line: `SELECT pg_sleep(2), pg_sleep(2)` sleeps for only 2 seconds. But `SELECT pg_sleep(2), pg_sleep(3)` sleeps for 5 seconds.

Comment: @k314159 tried it in IntelliJ IDEA SQL console, in both cases all mentioned pg_sleep() functions are invoked, thus no difference

Comment: Opinion: Not sure what the purpose of this is exactly, but using a server side wait seems better than DB side waiting - why tie up a connection and DB resources unnecessarily? As to why it doesn't work for you - no clue. Check what exactly is being passed in and if Postgres support parameter binding to that function. Seems also from the docs that the sleep happens after the * data is processed, so you might get that first row of data too early and then cause the wait.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the reply, after all I consider to wait on the server side, but still trying to make work pg_sleep:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the correct decision on my problem, it looks so:

```
WITH sleep AS (select pg_sleep(:delay) AS sleep), 
ids AS 
(SELECT id FROM repayment_applications 
WHERE 
repayment_applications.correlation_id =:correlationId 
AND 
repayment_applications.status <>:status) 
SELECT * FROM repayment_applications 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM ids) 
AND 
(SELECT * FROM sleep) IS NOT NULL
```

Works both with direct query and using nativeQuery in JPA

Comment: But anyway as I was advised above it is better to use client side delay because in case of delaying on a DB side its depends on a particular DB and changing to another one could cause a few issues